# CVS2Git is generating blank dump file

Tags: git, cvs2svn, cvs2git

CVS2Git is generating blank dump file everytime I run the command:

```
 ./cvs2git --blobfile=git-blob.dat --dumpfile=git-dump.dat --username=NL475475-v --fallback-encoding='utf8' /cygdrive/d/NewIDM --sort="xsort.pl"
```

OR

```
./cvs2git --options=test.options --fallback-encoding utf-8 --sort="xsort.pl"
```

Somehow no error is displaying. The output shows:

```
 ----- pass 1 (CollectRevsPass) -----
 Examining all CVS ',v' files...
 /cygdrive/d/Projects/CVS_IDM/CVSROOT/checkoutlist,v
 /cygdrive/d/Projects/CVS_IDM/CVSROOT/commitinfo,v
 /cygdrive/d/Projects/CVS_IDM/CVSROOT/config,v
 /cygdrive/d/Projects/CVS_IDM/CVSROOT/cvswrappers,v
 /cygdrive/d/Projects/CVS_IDM/CVSROOT/editinfo,v
 ........
 ........

Done
Time for pass1 (CollectRevsPass): 9476 seconds.
----- pass 2 (CleanMetadataPass) -----
Converting metadata to UTF8...
Done
Time for pass2 (CleanMetadataPass): 0.402 seconds.
----- pass 3 (CollateSymbolsPass) -----
Checking for forced tags with commits...
Done
Time for pass3 (CollateSymbolsPass): 0.178 seconds.
----- pass 4 (FilterSymbolsPass) -----
Filtering out excluded symbols and summarizing items...
Done
 ........
 ........

Time for pass14 (SortSymbolsPass): 0.216 seconds.
----- pass 15 (IndexSymbolsPass) -----
Determining offsets for all symbolic names...
Done.
Time for pass15 (IndexSymbolsPass): 0.028 seconds.
----- pass 16 (OutputPass) -----
Time for pass16 (OutputPass): 0.082 seconds.
```

### cvs2svn Statistics:

```
Total CVS Files:              2441
Total CVS Revisions:         23076
Total CVS Branches:          59701
Total CVS Tags:             603994
Total Unique Tags:             671
Total Unique Branches:         165
CVS Repos Size in KB:       101343
First Revision Date:    Tue Nov 18 20:34:27 2008
Last Revision Date:     Tue Oct 15 12:02:09 2013
```

---

### Timings (seconds):

```
9476   pass1    CollectRevsPass
   0   pass2    CleanMetadataPass
   0   pass3    CollateSymbolsPass
  58   pass4    FilterSymbolsPass
   1   pass5    SortRevisionSummaryPass
   0   pass6    SortSymbolSummaryPass
   0   pass7    InitializeChangesetsPass
   0   pass8    BreakRevisionChangesetCyclesPass
   0   pass9    RevisionTopologicalSortPass
   0   pass10   BreakSymbolChangesetCyclesPass
   0   pass11   BreakAllChangesetCyclesPass
   0   pass12   TopologicalSortPass
   0   pass13   CreateRevsPass
   0   pass14   SortSymbolsPass
   0   pass15   IndexSymbolsPass
   0   pass16   OutputPass
9537   total
```

I have been trying this from sometime now. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with the custom perl sort function. I've also tried GNU sort from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/. But it was not working. Now it works using latest updates (after 14-04-03):  UnxUpdates.zip at same page.